# Erro ao usar o seletor :hover

Tags: css

Boa Tarde,
Criei um projeto e estou usando HTML, CSS e JS no mesmo.
Criei um menu e apliquei o seletor :hover nos links, mas não funciona!
Obs: Estou usando o reset.css!

```css
body{
    background-color:#00a08f80;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

header{
    padding: 1em;
}

header img{
    width: 15em;
}

nav{
    position: absolute;
    top: 4.2em;
    left: 15em;
}

nav li{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 0 0 15px;
}

nav a{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover{
    font-weight: bold;
}

h1{
    color: #fee074;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #333;
    font-size: 1000px;;    
}

h2{
    color: #27575B;
}

.btn-yellow{
    background-color: rgb(254, 224, 116);  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/general.css">
    <title>Yellow Reach</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="assets/img/logo-yellow-reach.svg" alt="yellow-reach-logo">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="produtos.html">Produtos</a></li>
                <li><a href="planos.html">Planos</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://blog.yellowreach.com.br/">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="contato.html">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não funciona pq vc só importou o valor **`600`** da font **Open Sans**, para vc tb tem o que seria o estilo Regular ou Normal, vc precisa importar o valor **`400`** tb!

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Deveria ser assim, incluindo o valor 400

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

**OBS:** Repare tb que nessa indexação não tem o **style italic**, então se vc tentar o estilo itálico tb não vai dar certo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Execute o exemplo abaixo para ver a Open Sans com os dois pesos de font**

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<p style="font-weight: 600; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;">600 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p style="font-weight: 400; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;">400 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

Comment: Cara...você é um monstro!!!
Me ajudou muito!!!!!!
Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: @DimasFelippe legal que deu certo ai! Valeu a força, eu que fico feliz em ajudar!